# If I'm able to printf an array index with %x, how do I then save it into a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I see in the code I've inherited that the previous programmer `printf`s an array index out using %x. However, if I just try to append that same array index to a string with `+=` the string ends up being a bunch of symbols.

How do I append a variable that can be accessed with %x to the end of a string?

```
printf("%x", array[i]);
```

Is what the outputting code looks like.

But if I try:

```
string s = "";
s += array[0];
```

It just adds a weird symbol.

Comment: Show the relevant code please.

Comment: If you're really asking for [tag:c++] as you tagged, use `std::ostringstream`. If you want [tag:c] as your question sounds, use `sprintf()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not want to output it, I want to append it.

Comment: @DougSmith Yes, and? `std::ostringstream` is perfect for doing this?

Comment: What does the `std::` part mean?

Comment: @DougSmith You should take a basic tutorial or text book on [tag:c++] before asking here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices. You can use `sprintf` or one of it's cousins which work like `printf` *or* you can use `std::ostringstream`.

**`snprintf` example**

```
#include <cstdio>

char buffer[100] = "some text already there ";
std::snprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer), "%x", index);
```

.

**`std::ostringstream` example**

```
#include <sstream>

std::string text("some already existing text ");
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << std::hex << index;
text += buffer.str();
```

Comment: Where does index come from in the second example?

Comment: The same place it comes from in the first example. It's whatever you want to print.

Comment: I would use lexical_cast to convert int to string (see Herb Sutter long discussion about conversion http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your predecessor was *not* printing "an array index", and neither are you. `i` is the index; `array[i]` is the element at that index.

You didn't tell us what the types of these things were, but if we suppose that it is a pointer (guessing from the fact that your program compiles, and that your predecessor chose to output it as a hex string in the `printf` call), then your problem is that you are trying to perform string concatenation on a pointer, and not on the human-readable *representation* of that pointer.

Now, the C++ I/O streams in the standard library have built in lexical conversions that do this for you.

```
/** Example 1 */
// Output like: 0xDEADBEEF
void* somePtr = foo();
printf("%x\n", somePtr);

/** Example 2 */
// invalid unless somePtr is a valid C-string really
std::string str1 = somePtr;   

/** Example 3 */
// Does the translation to human-readableness for us
std::cout << std::hex << somePtr << '\n'; 

/** Example 4 */
std::stringstream ss;

// Does the translation to human-readableness for us
ss << somePtr;

// Now get a string back out of it
std::string str2 = ss.str();
```

We'd have to know more about your use case to help further.

Answer (score -1):

In order to convert c string to std::string do:

```
#define LENGTH 100
char cstr[LENGTH] = "something";
std::string cppstr(cstr, cstr+strlen(cstr));
```

In order to append:

```
cppstr.append(cstr, cstr+strlen(cstr));
```

Comment: Why would you use `strlen` instead of `LENGTH`, there?

Comment: @Lightness because strlen <= LENGTH (unless you have a bug)

Comment: That wasn't clear from your code before :) BTW ew `#define` plz2use `static const unsigned int`.

Comment: @Lightness std::string does not need the null pointer

Comment: No, but you'd better have one in your C-string!

Comment: @Lightness my C-string has a null pointer. "something" is an abbreviation to {'s','o','m' ... .'g', 0}

Comment: Yes, I never said it didn't. That array is mutable, though. No guarantee what else you might do with it or how many characters it may contain. If you have 99 characters in it, then you should have a _NUL_ in the 100th element, then `strlen(cstr)` is 99 and `LENGTH` is 100. That's the `+1` I was referring to.

Comment: @Lightness agreed to the fullest